# Move chapter number to chapter title in classicthesis

Tags: numbering, positioning, chapters, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis 4.1` in LyX to write my thesis and I need help to relocate the chapter number.

The top half of the image shows what I have

The bottom half shows what I want:

[image: problem]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\normalfont\fontfamily{pplj}\fontsize{35}{36}\selectfont}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
  {\relax}{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}{1em}
  {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]% 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The fact that `classicthesis` (wrongly) uses `\newfont` doesn't mean you can. ;-)

Comment: @egreg hehe! I was expecting exactly that comment from you :-) I'll made the change to the proper way in a few minutes (lunch time).

Comment: Thank you very much, Gonzalo Medina!

I don't know if it's your area of expertise, but I have some other problems with classicthesis:

I can't seem to change the natbib numerical citation style to Auther et al., XXXX.

I have this current line, however, I cant find the right place to put it:

    \usepackage[authoryear,round,colon]{natbib}

Present situation:
http://i.imgur.com/uyztUCi.png

Desired result:

http://i.imgur.com/Dg1matO.png

Comment: @user212704 This new issue is not related to the question here. Please open a new fresh question with this new requirement.

Comment: @egreg now it's fixed!

Comment: I would add `\normalfont` at the beginning, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add something to Gonzalo's answer, this one takes care of the options `eulerchapternumbers` and `linedheaders`, which can be passed to `classicthesis`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@eulerchapternumbers}}% font for the chapter numbers
    {\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{18}{19}\selectfont}}%
    {\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pplj}\fontsize{25}{26}\selectfont}}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
    {%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\relax}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\\\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }{%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\relax}{{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Output with

```
\usepackage{classicthesis}
```

[image]

and with

```
\usepackage[linedheaders]{classicthesis}
```

[image]

Comment: You could improve on this by using the right method for font selection as has been done in the awnser you build up on.