# (lyx) Chapter Number after Part Number (Chapter 4.4 instead of Chapter 4)

Tags: numbering, lyx, chapters, lyx-layouts

I know its counter-intuitive and doesn't make any sense at all, but bear with me. I am using the classic thesis style (in lyx), and the recommendation of my university ask me to do so. So currently My structure is something like this

```
Part 1 Introduction
  Chapter 1 AAAAA
  Chpater 2 BBBBB
  Chapter 3 CCCCC

Part 2 Something
  Chapter 4 DDDDD
  Chapter 5 EEEEE
  Chpter  6 FFFFFF
```

I need it turned into something like this

```
Part 1 Introduction
  Chapter 1.1 AAAAA
  Chpater 1.2 BBBBB
  Chapter 1.3 CCCCC

Part 2 Something
  Chapter 2.1 DDDDD
  Chapter 2.2 EEEEE
  Chpter  2.3 FFFFF
```

Needless to say, If the esctions and subsections can also ripple down like that  That'd be great.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I received a suggestion to use

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}}
```

The results look great. However, classic thesis does not support decimal points in chapter number (and it looks ugly).

[image: Ugly solution]

So I looked around the net and from this [Move chapter number to chapter title in classicthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130848/move-chapter-number-to-chapter-title-in-classicthesis), My chapter numbers look more acceptable like this

[image: Good One]

However, the chapter numbers do not reset when we change parts.

Suggestions?

EDIT: The counterwithin command bugs out the pdf bookmark like this, and when I use the LaTeX solution, this doesn't happen.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With other words,  the part number should precede the chapter number etc.? With normal `LaTeX`, the command is `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}}`. Since (sub)sections obtain their number format from `\thechapter`, the numbering cascade should go on ;-) I have no clue for LyX, since I do not use it.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem I asked for (used as a preamble). However, the classic thesis doesn't support decimal points as chapter numbers on the left hand side (it's a different font)

Comment: Well, I just test it with a small document with `classicthesis`. Well, it looks awkward with decimal points, but another problem is, that `\part` does not reset the chapter number, but this can be cured easily

Comment: Made it look slightly better (see Original Post). Can you suggest what to do to reset the chapter number ? I have not scripted in Tex before, but do have a small programming back ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer, but too long for a comment and good highlighting. It is not meant to keep it.

For resetting, you have to add it the reset list (;-))

In the preamble, say after the last `\usepackage{}`, but before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother
```

This will reset the chapter number when a new part starts!

Comment: Thanks, here is the final code I am using

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{chapter}}
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}

Comment: @RoverEye: Ok, but please enclose those commands with the `\makeatletter .... \makeatother` pair. And happy `texing` ;-) I hope, you enjoyed the `dark side` of using direct `\LaTeX` commands ;-)

Comment: Ah, but the thing is when I use the \makeatletter .... \makeatother commands, lyx hates it for some reason, and doesn't compile.

Comment: @RoverEye: Really? Well, I have not used `lyx` so far. I wonder, that the `\@addtoreset` command works at all, since commands with `@` only work when `\makeatletter` has been specified before or if they are in a `.sty` file.

Comment: Lyx is a front end for LaTeX. So that might entirely be possible. Yes the addtoreset works, since the chapter numbers are reset every time the part changes :)

Comment: To clarify: LyX has an area where you can type commands that go directly into the preamble (which goes after the various parts of the preamble it generates automatically). LyX does indeed surround the LaTeX entered there with a \makeatletter / \makeatother pair.

Comment: @JimOldfield: Thanks for that information. Since I do not use LyX at all, I very limited knowledge of it

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `chngcntr` package:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
```

both will reset the chapter counter each time a new part begins *and* will prefix the chapter counter with the part counter.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this seems to break classic thesis for some reason. However, the LaTeX solution offered below works.

Comment: ?? I tried with `classicthesis`, but didn't notice anything. What's broken?

Comment: The PDF bookmarks add the word "chapter" in front of every bookmark? Do keep in mind that I am using Lyx ? Or is it something that only I am seeing ?

Comment: @Rover Eye: I cannot imagine that the solution with the `\counterwithin` command interferes with `classicthesis`. And I wonder which connection to bookmarks might exist

Comment: OK. I couldn't keep Lyx in mind as I don't have it on my system: I only can give general answers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, just updated the OP with a picture of what I am seeing.

Comment: @RoverEye: Try to comment out `\counterwithin{chapter}{part}` for a moment and recompile, but keep the `\usepackage{chngcntr}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Did it. Doesnt bug out the bookmarks. I think its the counterwithin line

Comment: @RoverEye: I just checked with the code I used for testing with `classicthesis` this morning about your request, this time using Bernard's approach -- it works like charm and there are no strange bookmarks

Comment: Strange. Should I submit a bug report to the LyX devs ?

Comment: @RoverEye: No, not so fast ;-) Could you make a copy of your document, strip it down of everything personal information and add some dummy chapters/sections and then exporting to a `true` (the dark side, you know ;-)) `*.tex` file and send it to my mail address (see my profile page)?

Comment: @RoverEye: I got your mail and try to figure out why there is some 'error'

Comment: @RoverEye: I checked the file and found no possible source of the error you reported. See my mail to you